# Is a matrix element of a norm continuous representation always a trigonometric polynomial?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\pi:G\to {\mathcal B}(H)$ be a unitary representation of a compact group $G$ in a Hilbert space $H$. Consider a matrix element of $\pi$, i.e. a function of the form 
$$
f(t)=\langle\pi(t)x,y\rangle,\quad t\in G,
$$
where $x,y\in H$.

If $H$ is finite-dimensional, then $f$ is a trigonometric polynomial, i.e. a linear combination of matrix elements of some unitary irreducible representations $\pi_i:G\to {\mathcal B}(H_i)$:
$$
f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\cdot\langle\pi_i(t)x_i,y_i\rangle,\quad t\in G,
$$
($x_i,y_i\in H_i$, and $\lambda_i\in{\mathbb C}$).

A question:

> Is the same true in the case when $H$ is infinite-dimensional and $\pi$ is norm continuous?

EDIT. Alexander Shtern explained me that the answer is "yes" - this follows from his  [recent paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS1061920808040134). After that I asked a question with a modified formulation in [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194829/is-a-matrix-element-of-a-norm-continuous-representation-always-a-trigonometric-p).

Comment: Is something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a norm continuous unitary representation of a compact group on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space?

Comment: A trivial example: let $\sigma:G\to B(H)$ be a unitary irreducible representation, and $H^{\mathbb N}$ be the countable "Hilbert power of $H$". Then $\pi(t)(x_1,x_2,...)=(\sigma(t)x_1,\sigma(t)x_2,...)$ is a norm continuous irreducible representation of $G$. Shtern says that if we vary the power of $H$ (i.e. take different cardinal numbers instead of ${\mathbb N}$) and add a finite set of similar Hilbert powers, this will be a description of all norm continuous representations.